# Read and write java socket without blocking

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I have a simple Java IO TCP server/client protoype, where the server is writing heavily to the client, and the client writes *occasionally* to the server.  Writing occurs a while loop, particularly in the `run()` method of a `Worker` thread, as is standard:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        // Server writes to client
        try {
            socket.getOutputStream.write(writeArray);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
}
```

This is in a while loop, so if I also included a read operation, it would block.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        // Server writes to client
        try {
            socket.getOutputStream.write(writeArray);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Server reads from client
        try {
            int read = socket.getInputStream.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
}
```

Is there a standard pattern on how to allow for occasional reads without blocking or heavily wasting CPU cycles?

Comment: You can read and write on separate threads.

Comment: Ya, I had thought about that too.  On one hand, I don't like to spawn tons of threads unless they are critical, but I guess it would give me read access without affecting the write thread at all.

Comment: For small amounts of data you might not need to do this, but for heavier traffic separate threads can become a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the available() method:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--.  Then you only need to read "if available".

Comment: Warning: available() is unreliable though. It's giving an *estimate*, as documentation states (and practice confirms).